# eclipse dies every few minutes with latest jdk saying 'out of space in CodeCache for adapters'

Tags: eclipse, java

Since I installed latest jdk (1.6.0_25) I am having a very annoying issue that constantly makes my eclipse restart. This happens while doing any action, not a big clean project or anything.

My environment is the following:

> win7, 64b
>
> eclipse Version: 3.6.2 (64b) Build id:
>   M20110210-1200
>
> java version "1.6.0_25" Java(TM) SE
>   Runtime Environment (build
>   1.6.0_25-b06) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b11, mixed mode)

Before I had a previous jdk version (not sure what number, but was 1.6.0_21 or so, also 64b).

Since I installed 1.6.0_25 my eclipse dies every few minutes. I get a dialog in the UI saying:

> Problems occurred while trying to save
>   the state of the workbench.   Internal
>   Error   out of space in CodeCache for
>   adapters

And the log shows:

> !SESSION Fri May 13 12:35:53 CEST 2011
>   ----------------------------------------- !ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4
>   0 2011-05-13 12:35:53.870 !MESSAGE
>   Exception launching the Eclipse
>   Platform: !STACK
>   java.lang.VerifyError: (class:
>   org/eclipse/osgi/framework/log/FrameworkLogEntry,
>   method: getThrowable signature:
>   ()Ljava/lang/Throwable;) Illegal
>   constant pool index   at
>   org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:200)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native
>   Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:620)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:575)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1408)

My eclipse.ini files has this:

```
-showlocation
-showsplash org.eclipse.platform
--launcher.defaultAction openFile
-vm c:/jdk1.6.0/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
-Declipse.p2.unsignedPolicy=allow
-Djava.library.path=d:\dev\SlikSvn\bin
-Xms256m
-Xmx768m
-Xss4m
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
-XX:CompileThreshold=5
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=10
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=70
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
-XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:+UseFastAccessorMethods
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
```

anyone has an idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's a posting from someone who has a possible workaround for the problem: http://www.apacheserver.net/trunk-build-problem-out-of-space-in-CodeCache-for-adapters-at1027069.htm

The suggested workaround is to add `-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=64m` to the JVM options.  If that doesn't help, try a bigger number.

(I believe that the code cache is allocated within permgen, so increasing the permgen heap size might help as well.  However, various hints in Oracle bug reports suggest that these problems are caused by fragmentation of the code cache, and that would suggest that preallocation is a sensible strategy.  But really I'm only guessing.)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Increasing the code cache size is a good idea but I added

> -XX:+UseCodeCacheFlushing

to the JAVA options for the JVM startup and this fixed the problem too. I know this StackOverflow issue is old, but I hope is saves another user some time.

Answer (score -1):

I found mistake in your **eclipse.ini**

```
-vm c:/jdk1.6.0/jre/bin/server/jvm.dll
```

vm i.e. virtual machine parameter is pointing to jdk **/jdk1.6.0** update it to **jdk (1.6.0_25)**

also increase memory sizes

```
-Xms256m  256>>512
-Xmx768m  786>>1024
```

Hopes that works

Comment: that is no mistake, I have my jdk (1.6.0_25) installed in c:/jdk1.6.0/